# Load JavaScript after AJAX data success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I begin with jQuery and I'm trying develop a web audio player using jQuery, AJAX & PHP,

I have a problem with loading jQuery script included in my DOM after the success of AJAX.

When I receive my data via AJAX, the included scripts in the DOM does not respond.

There is my code:

1: I send my data vi `onclick` link to AJAX script :

```
<a href="" onclick="getfile('<?php echo $file; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $file?></a>
```

2- AJAX receive my data with success via this function:

```
function getfile(audio) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php',
        data: {
            song: audio
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#playlist1').html(data); // I get data with sucess in playlist1 div but player.js which is supposed to read the link that I got from PHP script is not loaded 
        },
    });
}
```

I tried to put `player.js` in `getScript` before AJAX it work but I have a lot of bugs when I click in another link.

My question is: how can I load all my included scripts when the AJAX request completes? I heard about live function, but I don't know how to integrate `live()` in my case.

Comment: because when player first read the file from playlist it's empty..in your success event you should tell to player.js to read again the new playlist

Comment: I did that with $.getScript("js/player.js"); it work but when i change the album via onclick link i have the new playlist in the div but the player continues to read the first playlist selected ... it not work correctly, i think i'am using a bad method to load all my js after ajax success

Comment: Could you email me your script, or give me your access...if you say yes i would provide you my email address

Comment: no problem give me your mail and i will send you my app with zip format, Thank you!

Comment: robert.rozas.n@gmail.com...cheers